# enabling flash player in docker chrome and firefox browser containers

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, flash, firefox, docker

i want to execute selenium tests in docker containers using selenium/hub, selenium/node-chrome-debug and selenium/node-firefox-debug.

My application contains flash content, as flash plugin is not available/outdated in chrome and firefox docker container i couldn't proceed further.

Any idea on how to install flash plugin in docker chrome and firefox container ?

Comment: Not sure,  but have you tried this - `chrome://plugins/` ?

Comment: yeah i tried that too, installed flash player in browser opened by selenium but when script is ran again it's taking fresh installation of chrome i.e., all installed plugins are gone

Comment: you can enable after opening the browser or check if there is command line flag for same

Comment: I don't use dockers or Selenium but my understanding is that (Pepper) Flash is **built-in** to Chrome (since it's their own modified/secure Flash Player). Anyways take this _"fresh installation of chrome"_ to the url : **https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed** and tell me what happens. It should show a pop-up asking to "Allow Flash to Run".. PS: To auto-run, your Flash content must be `<embed>` with minimum `width="800" height="600"`

Comment: VC.One getting this plugin is not supported

Comment: @user1846675 use the **@** symbol to notify specific person. Lucky I checked now. I'm stumped. It's possible this is a Selenium limitation rather a Chrome issue (unless the Docker factor actually means _"with all plugins blocked"_?). What type of application you got (desktop?, mobile?) cos if this was a webpage with flash content then couldn't the browser's Dev Tools be enough to assess the flash part? All I'm saying is find a workaround for testing the flash content outside of Docker environment. Would've been good if you had coded your flash content to transmit feedback too